# HBase seems to write to a single node in the cluster

Tags: hbase

I have a small cluster of 3 nodes, with Hbase deployed on all 3 of the nodes. 
It seems that when writing data into Hbase cluster, everything initially seems to be going to the same node.

The following is my relevant hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://server1:8020/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2181</value>
</property>


<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>server1,server2,server3</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>/opt/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
</property>
```

The region-server logs always show that files are added to the same

```
2016-10-28 15:31:07,990 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.HStore:     
  Added hdfs://server1
2016-10-28 15:31:19,195 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.HStore: Added 
hdfs://server1
```

I hope somebody can provide some insight into this.

Comment: How did you understand that all data went to the only one node? Also please provide config files core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your hbase.rootdir property is saying all of your data is stored in that specific node in HDFS (under /hbase).

You probably want to configure HA for HDFS by defining a nameservice for your cluster, and set hbase.rootdir to something like

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://yournameservice/hbase</value>
</property>
```

See [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html) for more details.

Balanced data distribution in HBase also depends on your row key design. A bad row key design could potentially create hotspots.